# React: Nested json to table

Tags: json, reactjs

Пытаюсь перебрать JSON для представления в таблице, json имеет следующую структуру

```
info = {
                 "8786868": [
                     {
                         "id": 123,
                         "abc": "1erf",
                         "dft": "jnh",
                         "res": "uji"
                     },
                     {
                         "id": 123,
                         "abc": "1erf",
                         "dft": "jnh",
                         "res": "uji"
                     }
                 ],
                 "78765": [
                     {
                         "id": "989",
                         "abc": "ojyh",
                         "dft": "ijhn",
                         "res": "werf"
                     },
                     {
                         "id": "989",
                         "abc": "ojyh",
                         "dft": "ijhn",
                         "res": "werf"
                     }
                 ]
             },
```

Перебираю следующим образом,

```
function renderResult(){
    let result = [];
    Object.values(data).map(row => {
        result.push(<tr>{
            Object.values(row).map(group => {
                Object.keys(group).map(cell => {
                    return <td>{group[cell]}</td>
                })
            })
        }</tr>)
    })

    return result;
}
```

По итогу получаю только 2 tr элемента без ячеек, просьба, подсказать что делаю не так, Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без таблиц на div's можно сделать примерно так:

```js
// import React from 'react';

const info = {
  8786868: [
    {
      id: 1,
      abc: '1erf',
      dft: 'jnh',
      res: 'uji',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      abc: 'qqq',
      dft: 'www',
      res: 'eee',
    },
  ],
  78765: [
    {
      id: 3,
      abc: 'ojyh',
      dft: 'ijhn',
      res: 'werf',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      abc: 'ttt',
      dft: 'yyy',
      res: 'uuu',
    },
  ],
};

const cellStyle = { width: '7rem', border: '1px solid black' };

const App = () => {
  const keys = Object.keys(info);
  
  const header = (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <div style={cellStyle}>abc</div>
      <div style={cellStyle}>dft</div>
      <div style={cellStyle}>res</div>
    </div>
  );

  const renderKey = (key, idx) => {
    return (
      <div key={idx}>
        <div style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>{key}</div>
        {header}
        {info[key].map((row) => {
          return (
            <div key={row.id} style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
              <div style={cellStyle}>{row.abc}</div>
              <div style={cellStyle}>{row.dft}</div>
              <div style={cellStyle}>{row.res}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return <div>{keys.map(renderKey)}</div>;
};

// export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```